# SwiftUI Picker in List adding extra row on top when using sections

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-picker

I have a SwiftUI inline picker in a list.  It works fine however when I enclose it in a section, an empty row appears on top of each section with an inline picker.  Is there anyway to remove this empty row?  If I remove the section the empty row disappears.

```
@State var color: String = "Red"
var colors: [String] = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]

var body: some View {
    List {
        Section(header: Text("Colors")) {
            Picker("", selection: $color) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                    Text(color)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Picker("", selection: $color) {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Text(color)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: just add `.labelsHidden()` to the `Picker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the init to `init(selection:content:label:)` with an empty label fixes the issue

```
Section("Colors") {
    Picker(selection: $color) {
        ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
            Text(color)
        }
    } label: {}
    .pickerStyle(.inline)
}
```

or as mentioned in the comments by @workingdogsupportUkraine you can also use the modifier `.labelsHidden()`

```
Section(header: Text("Colors")) {
    Picker("Picker", selection: $color) {
        ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
            Text(color)
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
    .labelsHidden()
}
```